# The lady or the tiger problem in Z3Prover

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am trying to use [Z3Prover](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) to prove the lady or the tiger problem as stated below:

There are three rooms. Each contains either a lady or a tiger but not both. Furthermore,
one room contained a lady and the other two contained tigers. Each of the rooms has a
sign, and at most one of the three signs was true. The three signs are:

```
Room I: A TIGER IS IN THIS ROOM.
Room II: A LADY IS IN THIS ROOM.
Room III: A TIGER IS IN ROOM II.
```

Which room contains the lady?

I know that the answer is that the lady is in room 1 and so the third statement is true and the others are false. But I don't know how to write the boolean proof in Z3, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# One boolean for each sign's correctness:
sign1, sign2, sign3 = Bools('sign1 sign2 sign3')

# If True, then it has a tiger, otherwise it has a lady
room1, room2, room3 = Bools('room1 room2 room3')

# Room I: Tiger is in this room.
s.add(sign1 == room1)

# Room II : Lady is in this room.
s.add(sign2 == Not(room2))

# Room III: A tiger is in Room II.
s.add(sign3 == room2)

# At most one of the signs are true
s.add(If(sign1, 1, 0) + If(sign2, 1, 0) + If(sign3, 1, 0) <= 1)

# There is exactly one lady:
s.add(If(room1, 0, 1) + If(room2, 0, 1) + If(room3, 0, 1) == 1)

# There are exactly two tigers:
s.add(If(room1, 1, 0) + If(room2, 1, 0) + If(room3, 1, 0) == 2)

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print m
    s.add(Not(And([v() == m[v] for v in m])))
```

There's some redundancy in this encoding, for instance the last two conditions about tiger and lady counts imply each other. But it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

When I run this, I get:

```
[room3 = True,
 room2 = True,
 room1 = False,
 sign3 = True,
 sign2 = False,
 sign1 = False]
```

which indeed says Lady is in room 1, and only the third sign is correct. (Furthermore, this is the only solution since asserting its negation in the while loop results in an unsat case.)